# How to Debug Maven Resolution Problems?

Tags: maven

I have a project where several jars live on an internal artifactory repository. I can see them when I navigate via the web ui, the correct repository is configured in the project pom.xml, the correct versions are listed in pom.xml but `mvn clean install` keeps reporting:

```
[WARNING] The POM for com.techfirm.checkouts:collections:jar:0.00.15 is missing, 
no dependency information available
```

and

```
    [ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project blah-txt-webapp: 
Could not resolve dependencies for project
com.techfirm.checkouts:blah-txt-webapp:jar:0.00.07-SNAPSHOT: 
The following artifacts could not be resolved:
com.techfirm.checkouts:collections:jar:0.00.15: 
Failure to find com.techfirm.checkouts:collections:jar:0.00.15 in 
https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, 
resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]
```

Clealy something basic is wrong but how can I debug this? Ideally I'd like to see what exact URLs and response code that it's trying to retrieve to at least give some clue as to whether it's even trying the internal repository before looking at repo.maven.apache.org. Or is there some other way you would resolve this issue normally?

Comment: did you try to run it with `-X` option? it means debug mode for the build, hence much more verbose. Also, are you sure `com.techfirm.checkouts:collections:jar:0.00.15` exists (which would be `collections-0.00.15.jar`) in maven repository?

Comment: Maven prints out the url of the artefact is trying to download. If you have several repos, it will print one log entry per repo (until if finds a repo that has the artefact). It looks like you might only be contacting maven central rather than artifactory (and artifactory should proxy to maven central).

Comment: you can run maven with a "-U" option to force artifact update. And use "mvn dependency:tree" to display a tree of dependencies. Have a look at http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/

Comment: In addition to the comments above me, what do you see in the Artifactory request.log? There should be an entry on that requests and that might shed some light on the issue.